# When is it correct to use the "-wise" suffix?

Tags: grammaticality, suffixes

I found myself writing the following in a bit of technical documentation:

> The Trainers' and Students' clients have very little in common, both user interface-wise and code-wise.

At first, I wondered whether I should have written *user-interface-wise*, *user interface-wise*, *user interface wise* or *user interfacewise*... or some other combination. A quick Google search [suggested](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/-wise) however that the "-wise" suffix actually isn't one you can or should use on any word.

What do you suggest? I guess the easiest way out is rephrasing (e.g., *not only for what concerns the user interface, but also for actual methods*), but I wanted to learn whether appending "-wise" to arbitrary words is incorrect, frowned upon or merely a stylistic choice.

Comment: I'd go with it being stylistic (I believe there was a mention of this very subject in Strunk and White); but your rephrasing sounds better to the ear for me. :) (Alternatively, "...in both the aspects of user interface and code".)

Comment: Not to be picky, but "-wise" is actually being used as a suffix, not a prefix - may want to edit the question's title.

Comment: @Will Done, thanks. (Aww, I totally expected that "ff" to form a ligature.)

Comment: Offtopic: The excessive use of *-wise* is parodied in the 1960 classic film [ *The Apartment* ](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0053604/quotes): "That's the way it crumbles, cookie-wise", "Premium-wise and billing-wise, we are eighteen percent ahead of last year, October-wise", etc.

Comment: Note that the correct hyphenation, validity of the -wise suffix notwithstanding, would be *user-interface-wise*.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[TheFreeDictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/-wise) gives this usage note:

> Usage Note: The suffix *-wise* has a
>   long history of use to mean "in the
>   manner or direction of," as in
>   *clockwise*, *otherwise*, and *slantwise*.
>   Since the 1930s, however, the suffix
>   has been widely used in the vaguer
>   sense of "with respect to," as in *This
>   has not been a good year saleswise.
>   Taxwise, it is an unattractive
>   arrangement.* Since their introduction,
>   these usages have been associated with
>   informal prose, and they are still
>   considered by many to be awkward. For
>   this reason, they might best be
>   avoided, especially in formal writing.
>   The most obvious alternative is to use
>   paraphrases, as in *This has not been a
>   good year with respect to sales. As
>   far as taxes are concerned, it is an
>   unattractive arrangement.*

The meat of this suggests that using *-wise* to mean *with respect to* is considered informal and even awkward. I suspect that pushing the boundaries as you do in the examples to include such constructions as *user interface-wise* makes an awkward usage even more awkward, as your own instincts seem to suggest. I generally have no problem with informal speech or writing in informal settings *or for emphasis*, but whenever I feel I am pushing the envelope I'll pause, think, and probably recast the sentence.

Comment: One of the problems with the particular example *user interface-wise* is that while it needs to be parsed as *(user interface)-wise*, the most immediate parsing would probably be *user (interface-wise)*, since hyphens typically bind tighter than spaces.  Occasionally I find myself really wanting something like this, in which case I’d usually go with *user-interface-wise* to avoid the parsing problem, but this is definitely just the lesser of two evils — it’s still awkward, since *user-interface* is unidiomatic.  This is where I wish we could German word-treatment in-English-transparently-use…

Comment: @PLL: The English way to punctuate that is with an en dash: user interface–wise.

Answer (score 3):

Elements of Style (Strunk and White) mentions it as something to avoid. Try instead:

They have little in common with respect to user interface and code.

or better:

They mostly disagree with respect to user interface and code.

Comment: minus 1,000,000 points for using that book as a reference! (j/k)

Comment: Firstly, Strunk and White is not an authority but an opinionated guide (a great one, though!), and secondly it in fact says "Not to be used *indiscriminately* as a pseudosuffix" (emphasis mine) and even "There is not a noun in the language to which *-wise* cannot be added if the spirit moves one to add it." :-)