# Use of "-wise" in phrases or words

Tags: meaning, grammar, suffixes

What is *-wise* in phrases or words that end with it? How do we use it correctly?

> Floor is obscenely expensive **computational-wise**.

I found a similar thread [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6713/when-is-it-correct-to-use-the-wise-suffix)
but I don't understand much.

Comment: Bonus points: Someone explain where the word "piecewise", as in a function that isn't continuous at all points, comes from.

Comment: The simple way to express "in words that end with it" is "as a suffix"; and it's usual to indicate suffixes in discussion with a leading hyphen, thus "What is the meaning of the suffix '-wise'?"

Answer (score 17):

The question you referred to in yours gives more usage notes on *when* you should use the "-wise" suffix, but not so much in terms of what it means. In this case, "wise" is supposed to serve as a [suffix](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/-wise) which means:

> with reference to: profitwise ; businesswise

The example you quoted would be less ambiguous if they had used "computation-wise". (Computational-wise seems ungrammatical to me). That is, the sentence is saying that:

> Floor is obscenely expensive [in terms of] computation

or,

> Floor is obscenely expensive computationally

Comment: Except in the case of the original of this kind *clockwise* (and *anti-clockwise*), and though *wise* tends to be extensively used as a suffix, excessive use of it is generally not well regarded as good - meaning elegant - English, among the likes of the liberal arts intelligentsia. At least that's the case in Britain.

Answer (score 4):

To quote a different source from the cited question, I'll use [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/wise):

> a suffixal use of wise - in adverbs denoting manner, position, direction, reference, etc.: counterclockwise; edgewise; marketwise; timewise.

To simplify this definition, you can think of *-wise* as "in the direction of", "in the manner of" or "with regard to", depending on the situation.

The sentence you provided falls obviously in the third case.

Comment: I used Dictionary.com too, just a more to-the-point definition

Comment: @simchona: Yep, I was writing while you posted your answer and didn't see. Anyway, my "different source" was regarding [this answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6713/when-is-it-correct-to-use-the-wise-suffix/6718#6718) related to the link provided by the OP.

Comment: @Gurzo-Ah, I see. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 3):

*Clockwise* means *in relation to a clock*.

> Floor is obscenely expensive computational wise.

It's not a very well written sentence, but it means the "floor" operation is obscenely expensive in relation to computation.

Comment: I think a better definition of clockwise is 'the direction that the hands of an analog clock move.' Often generalized to movement to the right. This also helps to explain counter-clockwise = move in the opposite direction to clockwise, or generally move to the left.

Comment: Yes, that's a good general definition but doesn't really explain the -wise suffix.

Answer (score 1):

"by means of" or "in the manner of" or "via".

A piecewise function is one that is analyzed piecewise, i.e., in pieces, because its discontinuities prevent analysis as a whole.

I would not accept "computational-wise" as grammatical; "computation-wise" would be the expected form, but it would be simpler and more idiomatic to just say "computationally".

Answer (score 0):

*-wise* is a prefix used to:

- form adjectives or adverbs meaning "(that is) in the manner, form, or direction of"
- form adverbs meaning "as regards, in terms of"

*Computational-wise* means "in terms of computation."